# Validate form with no id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that has elements without ID's because the same form is created several times using a while loop.  I am trying to validate it but can't think how to get the element values if there are no ID's to get them from.  I have searched the internet to try and the element's name but because the name is also repeated each time the form is created that doesn't work either.

Is there a simple way to validate this type of form?

Comment: Use jQuery validate. It works on name attributes. Plus you can wrap each different form inside a separate div with unique id and scope the validation call like `$('#formId', '#divId')`

Comment: What identifying information do you have? Do the forms have an id? Or do you just check the n-th form?

Comment: Don't write JS code that validates individual fields unless you _really_ can't help it: instead add some sort of attributes or classes to the fields to describe what validation is required and then write more generic JS that just loops through all of the fields of a specified form.

Comment: you can create id's dynamically in your while loop and use them

Comment: as far as I understand, you can change your code in the Loop and make id for them for example: `var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.id = "myUniqueId";`

Comment: @achakravarty Agreed. However to address the ID part of the question, you can generate incrementing ids (eg `#box1`, `box2`, etc). Though this is not recommended.

Comment: The name shouldn't be repeated as that's the key against which form values will be posted. Do you have a snippet you can provide? Are you in control of the form generation? You will need something to choose how to validate the field, what are you matching against the type eg text, numeric, email or do you have classes set?

Comment: @MatthewRiches - There's nothing wrong with having elements of the same name in separate forms. (Actually there's nothing wrong with having multiple elements of the same name in the same form, but I don't think the OP is doing that here.)

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry thought he said one form with repeating fields. I think W3C would moan about fields with the same name in the same form though.

Comment: @MatthewRiches - No, repeated name in a form is perfectly acceptable. An example where you'd do it is when you have repeating line items within a form (where each line might have fields with `name="productid"` and `name="qty"`).

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah you are right, just checked. Seems to be fine, although I can see a good reason to do so unless is something like foo[]

Comment: @MatthewRiches - there are multiple forms and none of the names are repeated in the same form.  Each form is identified with a unique ID by appending the ID with a value created in the while loop (form1, form2, form3 etc).

Comment: @tatty27 So the answer is to add a class to the field type (class="email") or use an HTML5 type and then do your validation on groups of elements just like nnnnnn says.

Comment: that probelm is that I have four selects with the same class name (used for enabling and disabling them in a different function), I need to check that at least one of those selects has a value if a further select menu called grade has a value that isn't 1

Comment: That issue with the selects sounds easy enough - are you saying each form has these five select elements and you want to validate only those within whichever form the user tries to submit? Please click "edit" and add that explanation to your question with a sample of the html. That way if somebody wants to post some JS/jQuery to do that for you they will use your class and field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms fields should not really validate by identification (i.e. unique), they should validate by type (achieved with classes or name attributes).

Eg an email field may have the class `.validate-email`. In jQuery you iterate through ALL email fields using `.each()`:

```
$('.validate-email').each(function() {
    $field = $(this);
    // do your validation here...
});
```

Or you could use action functions such as `.keyup()`:

```
$('.validate-email').keyup(function() {
    $field = $(this);
    // do your validation here...
});
```

Edit to address comments:

Say you have:

```
<form id="student_form">
  <!-- some fields... -->
  <div>
    <select class="grade"><!-- markup... --></select>
    <select class="reason_select"><!-- markup... --></select>
    <!-- as many as you want -->
    <select class="reason_select"><!-- markup... --></select>
  </div>
  <-- more fields... -->
</form>
```

On form submit, perhaps you could try:

```
$("form#student_form").submit(function(form_event) {
    var $grade = $(this).find(".grade");     
    var valid = true;
    if ($grade.val() != "1") {
       $grade.siblings(".reason_select").each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() == "") // or whatever is appropriate
               valid = false;
       })
    }
    valid || form_event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm not sure how that would work.  I have a select called grade and 4 further selects with a class called 'reason_select'.  If grade is not 1 then at least one of the reason_selects should have a value

Comment: So this validation is on form submit only?

Comment: Looks like you independently arrived at nearly the same solution as me. Note that you need to declare the `e` argument in your submit handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh, missed that. I changed the code from `return valid;` to `valid || e.preventDefault();` without declaring the param...

Answer (score 0):

When creating the controls in a loop, you may create unique `name` or `ID` values for the controls.

```
txt1
txt2
txt3
txt4
txt5
```

So, if it is PHP, you may do `"txt<?php echo count; ?>"` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above. 
The reason why you cannot validate this form is because you have the same/or similar selectors to your forms.

Give the forms identical IDs (it can be be like `<form id="form1">` or somewhat like that.
After you have forms that don't match with other forms you should do the same with the input fields inside. However, here you can use classes instead, because you can use the form ID for selecting the input field with jQuery validate (example: `$('#form1 .txtUserName').validate(/* Your functions and other specifications goes here */);`).

Hope this helps. :)

/J.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with an array of similar elements, you can use a `ul > li` approach (the `ul` needs an ID, of course).

```
<ul id="elementList">
    <li><!-- element1 --></li>
    <li><!-- element2 --></li>
    <li><!-- element3 --></li>
</ul>
```

Then, with jQuery you could access this with something like that:

```
$('#elementList').each(function(index){
    validateElement(index);
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have a select called grade and 4 further selects with a class called `reason_select`. If grade is not 1 then at least one of the `reason_selects` should have a value."*

Assuming all of your forms have these five select elements, and that you want to validate just those for whichever individual form gets submitted, you can do something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this),
        reasonHasVal = false;
    if ($form.find('select[name="grade"]').val() != "1") {
       $form.find("select.reason_select").each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() != "") {
               reasonHasVal = true;
               return false;
           }
       });
       if (!reasonHasVal) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("Please select a reason.");
       }
    }
});
```

The key is using the [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find) to only deal with the elements within the form in question.